# angularjs csv download to local

Tags: angularjs

I made the service side to return csv format when I call the service with $http Get with Angular if the user click the button..

```
So the return is like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

What is the best way to give the user the way to save it their local machine?

Comment: if your server is already creating the data in a format that is acceptable to your user, can the button just forward them to that URL (making sure that the mime type is correct, of course!)

Comment: You're best off pushing the download to the user using the server.  What server architecture do you have (eg PHP or Java or Node)

Comment: But the tricky thin is that the service can only accept POST.. If the service can accept GET, there is no problem to redirect the user.. But How can I do it with POST?

Comment: @Rok First you are talking about GET, now about POST. What are you looking for? I also don't get why you need to retrieve the CSV if its anyway just for downloading? Simply add a link to your API (or whatever the CSV comes from) and you are done, aren't you?

Comment: Yep.. I was confused.. Forward traffic to API directly will solve my problem... thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two options

1) Send the csv from your server.

2) Data URIs. I think this is what you're asking for.  Here is an example

```
/**
 * @param{string} content The contents of a file to download.
 * @param{string} fileName The name to save the file as on the user's computer.
 */
function(content, fileName) {
  var dataUrl = 'data:text/csv;utf-9,' + encodeURI(content);
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  angular.element(link)
    .attr('href', dataUrl)
    .attr('download', fileName) // Pretty much only works in chrome
  link.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) library, which can save data in CSV format one line:

```
 function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.filename = "mydata.csv";
    $scope.cities = [{city:"Odessa",population:100000},
                  {city:"Voronezh",population:201022},
                  {city: "Paris", population: 3000000}];

    $scope.saveCSV = function(filename, content) {
          alasql('SELECT city, population INTO CSV("'+$scope.filename+'",{headers:true}) FROM ?',
           [$scope.cities]);
    };
 };
```

See [the full example code](http://jsfiddle.net/tmsoobot/1/) in jsFiddle.

In this example Alasql use SELECT operator to choose required fields from data array (AngularJS'  creates $$hashKey field, which probably is not needed to users). If you do not use 
on these data simply export to CSV file with:

```
alasql('SELECT * INTO CSV('mydata.csv') FROM ?',[$scope.data]);
```